# why does geolocation not work on mobile browsers and desktop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, geolocation

I am trying to get the location of the user with HTML5 geolocation. On Desktop Gives this error when I grant access 2: Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/': No response received. And when I test on a mobile phone, it does not ask the access question and error 1: User denied Geolocation

this is my code:

```
successHandler(position) {
  console.log(position)
  alert(position.coords.latitude)
  alert(position.coords.longitude)
},
errorHandler(errorObj) {
  alert(errorObj.code + ": " + errorObj.message);  
},
getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.successHandler, this.errorHandler, {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      maximumAge: 10000,
      timeout: 10000
    })
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}
created() {
  this.getLocation()
},
```

I am using Google Chrome on all devices.

Comment: Is your website served from HTTPS? This feature is only available in secure contexts

Comment: yes this is my code

Comment: module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    https: true
  }
}

Comment: in vue.config.js file

Answer (score 1):

1. Geolocation on Google Chrome requires connection with Google. As a result, if you are in a region where Google is banned, it cannot provide location service.
2. As other guys mentioned, geolocation requires HTTPS.